# returning serial primary key. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно при записи в базу данных возвратить id текущей записи.

Я делаю это так:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "category" (
  "id"        serial primary key,
  "tags"      text  default NULL,
  "smth"      text unique
);

do $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "category" (smth) VALUES ('234') RETURNING id;
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
                NULL;
END;
$$;
```

Но возникает ошибка:

```
[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data
  Где: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at SQL statement
```

Помогите разобраться

Comment: А куда вы хотите что бы он вернул ID ? Сделайте переменную в которую вернуть и укажите into или сделайте with из этого insert и select из него

Comment: @Mike, вообще, потом буду использовать данную конструкцию в psycopg2. Я просто не совсем понимаю, почему работает  просто `INSERT INTO "category" (smth) VALUES ('some text') RETURNING id;`, а при обработке исключений это не работает. Когда Вы сказали сделать select, Вы имели в виду это: `INSERT INTO "category" (smth) VALUES ('some text') with SELECT id;`?

Comment: как то так `with q (insert into .... returning id) select * from q`. Далась вам эта обработка исключений `insert into tab(smth) .... select 234 from DUAL where not exists(select 1 from tab where smth=234)`

Comment: @Mike, Конструкция с with дает ту же ошибку `[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data`. А обработку я использую, так это простая конструкция, которая мне понятна.  А то, что Вы написали после конструкции с with мне не совсем понятно (Только начинаю изучать postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void.

Инлайновый блок кода не может возвращать значение, во всяком случае сейчас. Так что не получится.

Если вы на `postgresql` 9.5, то используйте штатный `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...`.

Для более старых версий - лучше бы обновитесь до 9.5. Если никак - то можете написать полноценную именованную хранимку и вызывать её. Но `try .. catch` в `postgresql` штука не очень-то быстрая. Варианты с `CTE` и `insert ... select`, проверяющим перед вызовом `insert` наличие записей, на сколько помню изыскания и ответы с enSO, не гарантируют отсутствие нарушения уникальности. Но если конкурентность не очень высокая, то работает будет внятно. Можно добавить к этому [`pg_advisory_lock`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).

С `advisory lock` будет как-то так:

```
with data_for_lock as (
    select value from (values('232')) as data (value) 
    where not exists (
        select 1 from category where category.smth = data.value
    )
) 
insert into category (smth) 
    select value from data_for_lock 
    where pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(('x' || substr(md5(value),1,16))::bit(64)::bigint)
returning id;
```

Сначала проверяется, нет ли уже таких значений в таблице по интересующему полю. Потом вызывается `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock`, который ответит `true`, если блокировку удалось захватить - и тогда строка пройдёт как данные для insert'а. Или вернёт `false` - т.е. кто-то параллельно эту блокировку захватил, тогда select эту строку пропустит и передаст insert 0 строк, что корректно. Освобождается блокировка, полученная через xact, только при `commit`, но автоматически (вне транзакции - сразу после выполнения запроса, т.к. запрос оборачивается в транзакцию неявно).

Следующие грабли - у `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock` 64-битный идентификатор. Т.е. крайне маловероятны, но возможны грабли с коллизией. Можно и это учесть, например, дёргать `pg_advisory_xact_lock`, после получения блокировки ещё раз проверять, нет ли таких записей в таблице. Повторюсь, лучше обновляйтесь до 9.5. Сообщество долго думало и пиналось, но `on conflict` сделало только в 9.5.

Comment: Вы меня извините, но не могли бы Вы написать полностью конструкцию, которая при новой записи проверяет возникновение ошибки на уникальность, и, если ее нет, возвращает значение id новой записи. Не понимаю, как это сделать.

Comment: `INSERT INTO "category" (smth) VALUES ('234') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id;`

Comment: Версия 9.4.7. Обновиться, к сожалению не могу.

Comment: Понял Вас, спасибо!